# Android Studio's machine can't change display orientation in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, orientation

I just installed **Android Studio 2 beta 6**. When I try to test an example app my emulated display doesn't switch to landscape. Lauching the emulator in landscape orientation didn't help and it is like in the picture below.
Works fine on Windows 10.

I know the older versions had bugs but in my case I don't know what the problem is.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if rotation is deactivated on the device? Otherwise this might be better suited for the **google bugtracker**.

Comment: rotation was set by default as auto